# Create SQL 'LIKE' Statment that looks for specific Patterns of numbers and letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

Is it possible to use LIKE in a SQL query to look for patterns of numbers and letters. I need to locate all records where the specific field data has the pattern (2 Numbers,1 hyphen, 3 Letters) ## - AAA I am using SSMS with SQL Server 2008. Any help would be appreciated. THANKS.

Comment: I think you will need regular expressions for that. Oracle has a `REGEXP_LIKE` function that is just like using `LIKE`, but with a regular expression. Unfortunately, I don't think MS SQL Server has any similar function, so I think you may have to write a procedure to help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think `LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%'` should work.

I'm not sure of your case sensitivity requirements but you can stick a COLLATE in as below.

```
select * from
(
SELECT 'GHSASKJK' AS T UNION ALL
SELECT 'HGGH11-ABC'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'HGGH11-abc' 
) f
WHERE T LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: Perfect. There is no case sensitivity for this situation but I appreciate the info for future use. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You should also be able to accomplish this with [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx).

```
Select *
From Table
Where PatIndex( '%[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%', Value) > 0
```

Comment: Why `PATINDEX` and not `LIKE`? Using `LIKE` is much more readable, IMHO.

Comment: @Ruben - It is an alternate, non-CLR solution to the same problem.

Comment: I have not seen `PatIndex` before. Thanks for expanding my knowledge

Answer (score 4):

If the data is exactly "##-AAA", you can just use `LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'`. If the data contains this sequence somewhere, use `LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%'`.

Note that if your column is indexed, `LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'` can be *a lot* faster than any UFD or CLR regex, because SQL Server understands `LIKE` better, and it can more easily skip parts of the index if it would never match. For example, all records starting with a character outside of 0-9 will be ignored immediately, whereas a UDF or CLR regex will still read these values.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating a CLR assembly with .Net. That way you can create a function or SP that can use regex.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

**Edit**: Even though this can be done via LIKE as stated in other answers, I would still recommend creating the assembly. If your data changes for some reason and you need an advanced way of looking up data, this regex assembly would be able to accomodate the change

Comment: Using CLR regexes is pretty much overkill for this. Also, using a `LIKE` when possible will usually be much faster, because it's native to SQL Server and it can use indexes better (if you can prevent an initial '%' or '_').

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this for future use. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a like search for this.  Your where clause would be similar to:

```
Where YourColumnName Like '%[0-9][0-9]-[a-z][a-z][a-z]%'
```

*** This assumes a case insensitive collation